# iFramed CloudPages and triggered emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, triggered-send, iframe

We are creating a public CloudPage with a (custom) lead capturing form. After the form is submitted, a triggered email (i.e. double opt-in) is sent to the new / potential customer. We would like to place that CloudPage with the form as an iFrame on our regular website. Will this affect the triggered email part in any way? Also, in the form, we validate the submitted email address value against our database in Marketing Cloud (i.e. if the email address already exists, the form prompts an error). Will this also be affected? Thanks

Comment: Why would you think this will be affected? Since the functionality you describe is implemented purely in backend, I see no issues here which might be caused by iframing the cloudpage (however I will really discourage you from doing so, and consider an AJAX based approach, utilising JSON code resorce)

Comment: To expand on @LukasLunow - You would have the form on your page directly and then have the AJAX call submit to a separate code resource page that is hosted in SFMC (Code Resource) that then processes the data as you want and triggers the email. This is the preferred method as it not only is an easier approach (no need or consideration of iFrames), but also removes the usage of SuperMessages per view since a Code Resource does not cost Super Messages.